# Interactive Maps using plotly shows lat and long as hover (needs to be datapoints) and does not work with 2 combined plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggmap

Here is my code - first problem, I can't combine the two plots and second I am struggling to use plotly to make it interactive; My data format is also included here;

[image: Data]

```
mapind <- read.csv("V2_tobacco_cancer_india2017.csv", header=T)
head(mapind)
attach(mapind)

mapbox.ind <- c(68.3,7.5,97.4,37.12)
mycol <- rgb(255, 0, 0, max = 255, alpha = 120, names = "red50")
mycol1 <- rgb(0, 0, 0, max = 255, alpha = 120, names = "blue50")
mycol2 <- rgb(0, 0, 255, max = 255, alpha = 120, names = "yellow50")
mycol3 <- rgb(34, 139, 34, max = 255, alpha = 120, names = "brown50")

inmap <- get_stamenmap(bbox=mapbox.ind, maptype="toner-lite", color = "color", zoom=6, crop=T, force=T)


p1 <- ggmap(inmap) +
  geom_point(data = mapind, aes(Long, Lat), col = mycol, cex = 0.3*SLT_Prevalence, pch = 16, show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(data = mapind, aes(Long, Lat), col = mycol1, cex = 0.3*Pharynx_Oral_cancer, pch = 16, show.legend = T) +
  geom_label_repel(data = mapind, aes(mapind$Long, mapind$Lat), label = states, size = 2, color = "black", nudge_y = -0.6, nudge_x = -0.6, fontface = "bold", segment.color = NA) +
  # geom_label_repel(data = mapind, aes(mapind$Long, mapind$Lat), label = states, size = 2, color = "black", nudge_y = 0, nudge_x = 0, fontface = "bold", segment.color = NA) +
  ggtitle("B) Smokeless tobacco (red) and Oral Cancer (black)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=7), axis.title=element_text(size=7,face="bold")) +
  annotate("label", label = "10 Oral Cancer Cases per 100K", x = 91, y = 11.3) +
  annotate("label", label = "10% SLT Prevalence", x = 91, y = 9.3)
  
p2 <- ggmap(inmap) +
  geom_point(data = mapind, aes(Long, Lat), col = mycol2, cex = 0.3*Smoking_Prevalence, pch = 16, show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(data = mapind, aes(Long, Lat), col = mycol3, cex = 0.3*Lung_cancer, pch = 16, show.legend = T) +
  geom_label_repel(data = mapind, aes(mapind$Long, mapind$Lat), label = states, size = 2, color = "black", nudge_y = -0.6, nudge_x = -0.6, fontface = "bold", segment.color = NA) +
  ggtitle("A) Smoking (blue) and Lung Cancer (green)") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=7), axis.title=element_text(size=7,face="bold")) +
  annotate("label", label = "10 Lung Cancer Cases per 100K", x = 91, y = 11.3) +
  annotate("label", label = "10% Smoking Prevalence", x = 91, y = 9.3)

p <- grid.arrange(p2, p1, ncol=2, 
                  top = text_grob("Prevalence of Tobacco Use and Associated Cancer Rates in India", 
                                  size = 14), 
                  bottom = text_grob("Source: Indian Council of Medical Research, Public Health Foundation of India, and Institute of Health Metrics and Evaluation 2017; Global Adult Tobacco Survey 2016-17", 
                                     size = 9))
 
p <- ggarrange(p1, p2, 
          labels = c("A", "B"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

ggplotly(p1) %>%
  highlight(
    "plotly_hover",
    selected = attrs_selected(line = list(color = "black"))
  ) %>%
  widgetframe::frameWidget()
```

Comment: This helped: https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-there-way-to-change-hovertext-in-plotly/8310

Comment: I got the hover text fixed using the Studio link above. But could not combine the plots as one in plotly.

Comment: Your code shows `ggplotly(p1)`.  That should give you one plot.  Have you tried `ggplotly(p)`?

Comment: Sorry the code wasn't updated. Ggplotly p didn't work either. Subplot did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: I want to appreciate the help provided by all above users in this thread and the stackoverflow community for your assistance in visualization of data in one of my upcoming publications. Kindly contact me if you do not consent to using your user ID in the acknowledgements. Thank you and all the best! Stay safe and healthy!!